# Replacing all entries in column in Pandas DF containing certain substring

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
     ID            Name
0     1       USA State
1     2          Canada
2     3           Egypt
3     4  Titicaca State
...
```

I want to replace all the `State` with `S`. So the result should look like

```
     ID            Name
0     1           USA S
1     2          Canada
2     3           Egypt
3     4      Titicaca S
...
```

I tried

```
DF.loc["State" in DF['Name']] = "S"
```

but got `KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` method, which can replace a regex pattern. Here use `\bState\b` to match the word `State` and replace it with `S`:

```
df['Name'] = df.Name.str.replace(r"\bState\b", "S")

df
#  ID         Name
#0  1        USA S
#1  2       Canada
#2  3        Egypt
#3  4   Titicaca S
```